# How to print output file using CMD BATCH and vba

Tags: r, vba, shell, wscript.shell

What arguments should I type after CMD BATCH args to produce an output file called my file.log?

```vb
Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitUntilComplete As Boolean: waitUntilComplete = True
    Dim errorCode As Long
    
    errorCode = shell.Run("""C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.1\bin\x64\R.exe""" & " CMD BATCH --vanilla " _
                & """--args C:\MyProject\RInt.xlsm"" " & """C:\MyProject\RunAll.R""", vbHide, waitUntilComplete)
```